# How to select different format of the date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, format

i have this table and i cant change its format to yyyy-mm-dd because i have so many scripts that are related to this format dd-mm-yyyy , it would be a mess if iam gonna change its format

```
Id            date

1         01-07-2014
2         02-07-2014
3         03-07-2014
4         05-07-2014
5         07-07-2014
6         14-07-2014
7         18-07-2014
8         19-07-2014
9         21-07-2014
10        01-08-2014
11        02-08-2014
12        03-08-2014
```

On the php file

```
$from = '01-07-2014';
$to = '02-08-2014';
```

i need to update some values from all the dates that are between 01-07-2014 and 01-09-2014    the format dd-mm-yyyy

iam using

```
  UPDATE successlog 
        SET successlog.overtime ='00:00'                
            Where date >= '$from' AND 
                  date <='$to'
```

its not working and am using the key between $from And $to also its not working

when the format was yyyy-mm-dd it was working normally but after i changed the format to 
dd-mm-yyyy its not working .

Comment: Why don't you use `date` or `datetime` datatype for your database columns? You can use `DATE_FORMAT()` to format the dates however you like.

Comment: WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from));
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to));
```

or in MySQL:

```
.. WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from','%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$to','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the format to yyyy-mm-dd in the sql only then it will work.

Try converting the $from and $to variable to yyyy-mm-dd format using PHP date function before adding the variable to sql string.

```
$from = '01-07-2014';

$from = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($from));


$to = '01-09-2014';

$to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($to));
```

Comment: I have this table and i cant change its format because i have alot of scripts that is related to the format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: try changing only in the sql string like UPDATE successlog 
        SET successlog.overtime ='00:00'                
            Where date >= 'date('Y-m-d',strtotime($from))' AND 
                  date <='date('Y-m-d',strtotime($to))'